SIMD, parallel, & gpu computing on Apple silicon
Consider a n x m matrix of floats, say A={a_{ij}}, with n and m very large. I want to compute an n x n symmetric matrix, say B={b_{ij}}, whose generic entry b_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{m} a_{ik}*a_{jk}/m, for all i<j in 1,…,n.
I am using this dummy problem to learn about the Apple silicon architecture. I wonder in particular

which would be the fastest implémentation possible on an Apple silicon, say a M3?

The computation of each b_{ij} is independent of the others and can be carried out in parallel. Which computing paradigm would be better suited in this case (parallelization on CPUs or on GPUs)?

The computation of each b_{ij} could be carried out by using SIMD. SIMD units  are apparently available on Apple silicon (even if it is unclear what they are? Maybe the neural units?) Are these instructions usable while computing in  parallel either on CPUs or on GPUs?


I did not try anything at the moment. Before proceeding, I am trying to understand which implementation strategy  I should use.

Are you aware of the fact that Apple Silicon is just an implementation of ARMv8.4? Its SIMD architecture is NEON, as documented in the ARMv8-A Reference Manual. Apple also has their proprietary, undocumented matrix extensions of which there has been some reverse engineering, but... there's just no guarantees about those. In general though, SIMD with large data sets sounds exactly like the task GPUs were made for.

If your matrix is sparse, then focus on algorithms before low-level CPU instructions.

@Nate: it’s dense unfortunately. Siguza: thanks for this information. I am actually struggling to find the appropriate documentation.

Please specify the target language if possible (or at least a list or even some information about while language would be used to start this computation)

@JérômeRichard: c/c++

Ok. Then Apple Accelerate might be the way to go. It has BLAS functions (including matrix multiplications) that can be used from a C code. This is for CPU computations (maybe not anymore on recent M CPUs). For the GPUs, there are libraries using OpenCL to do that but AFAIK OpenCL is not really officially supported anymore on Apple machines anymore, so Metal should be use instead (with far less support by libraries). See the answer of Soonts about this part. Note that Metal only runs on Apple machines as opposed to OpenCL (fully portable). AFAIK Apple Accelerate too.

You are very right about metal and OpenCL. The second is not supported anymore and metal is proprietary (beyond being horrible to read and to program). This is why I am searching for c/c++ libraries that can give me access to these intrinsics in a way similar to https://academic.oup.com/book/41811/chapter-abstract/354554875?redirectedFrom=fulltext. I was unsuccessful so far, though. It is even unclear to me if on this architecture the flow of operations on cpu, gpu, and the SIMD unit can be carried out simultaneously.

Looks like you want to compute a conventional matrix*matrix product with the same matrix on input, divided by a scalar constant afterwards?
I have never developed stuff for modern Apple hardware, but I would expect Metal Compute i.e. the GPGPU to be the fastest method available there. AFAIK their NPU can’t do FP32 precision, and their CPU SIMD is probably much slower than GPU.
As for the specific algorithm, the search keyword for multiplying large dense matrices is “tiled matrix multiplication”. Here’s an example in Direct3D 11 compute shader.
Because you multiply the matrix by itself, you don't need to compute all tiles. You only need tiles on one side of the diagonal, including the tiles directly on the diagonal. After the multiplication is complete, dispatch another (much cheaper) compute shader to transpose tiles across the diagonal.

Yes, in this example it is. My question is however more general and concerns the architecture of Apple silicon. It is not at all clear to me if neon instructions can be carried out simultaneously with gpu instructions and which type of instruction is in general faster

@DanielRosencat NEON instructions and GPU are independent pieces of hardware, they can run in parallel. Generally, when the work is massively parallelizable like multiplication of large matrices, integrated GPUs are way faster than CPU SIMD. For example, in my desktop I have Ryzen 7 8700G. FP32 FMA on CPU delivers about 1 TFlops (16-lanes AVX512 FMA each cycle, or 8-lanes AVX FMA twice per cycle, 8 cores, 4.2 GHz base frequency), while FP32 FMA on the integrated GPU delivers up to 8.3 TFlops.

Back to the Apple, the integrated GPU of Apple M3 Max delivers up to 10.65 TFlops. I wasn’t able to find NEON SIMD FMA throughput for M3 but it’s probably much slower than the integrated graphics in terms of FLOPS.

I see. So the way to proceed is to move computation on GPU. This means to use metal. All of the examples that I have seen so far use the tandem  Swift + Metal. Do you know if it is possible to use C/C++ and metal instead?

@DanielRosencat I don’t have personal experience, but it seems Apple has C++ language projection: https://developer.apple.com/metal/cpp/

very interesting! I did not know it. I give a look!
